# find row wise index of specific elements in a matrix and populate another matrix

Tags: arrays, r, matrix, indexing, signals

I have a matrix of 10 stock returns for 100 days ( 100 rows and 10 columns ) . I am applying the following operations on it.

I have used loops which takes a very long time on a bigger data set. I'm sure this can be simplified using array operations.

1) select the top 3 and bottom 3 values in each row and store the index of the values in a "select" matrix (also a 100x10 vector) as a "1"

```
Ret=array(rnorm(1000),dim=c(100,10))
select=array(rep(0,1000),dim=c(100,10))

Ret.top <- t(apply(Ret, 1, order, decreasing=T)[1:3,])
Ret.bottom <- t(apply(Ret, 1, order, decreasing=F)[1:3,])

for( i in 1:dim(Ret)[1])
{
select[i,Ret.top[i,]]=1
select[i,Ret.bottom[i,]]=1
}
```

2) I then have a vector of signals that has been computed for all stocks each day ( signal matrix , 100 by 10). For the selected stocks in the above step, I check the signals and select the stock with 2 highest signals and also stocks with 2 lowest signals and store their index in a longshort matrix. ( +1 for the highest signals and -1 for the lowest signals )

```
signal=array(rnorm(1000),dim=c(100,10))

longshort= array(rep(0,1000),dim=c(100,10))


for( i in 1:dim(Ret)[1])
{
    x=order(signal[which(select[i,]==1)],decreasing=T)[1:2]
    longshort[i,x]=1;
    y=order(signal[which(select[i,]==1)],decreasing=F)[1:2]
    longshort[i,y]=-1
}
```

Any help in converting these loops into array operations would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It seems you only use the 10 first signals in `signal[which(select[i,]==1)]`. Also, x will always be a number 1-6, so you never have any signals in longshort for indices 6-10!

Answer (score 1):

`ifelse` will do the job.

```
Ret.top <- t(apply(Ret, 1, rank))
select= ifelse(Ret.top <= 3 | Ret.top >=8,1,0)

longshort <-ifelse(Ret.top <= 2,-1,
              ifelse(Ret.top >= 9,+1,0) )
```

BTW, OP, I think you made a mistake with these lines. You are only selecting the first three rows, not the top-ranked rows.

```
Ret.top <- t(apply(Ret, 1, order, decreasing=T)[1:3,])
Ret.bottom <- t(apply(Ret, 1, order, decreasing=F)[1:3,])
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's what I've got so far:

```
Ret.ord <- apply(Ret, 1, order) # ascending order
select2 <- t(apply(Ret.ord, 2, function(x) { y<-integer(10); y[x[c(1:3,8:10)]] <- 1; y}))

all.equal(select, select2) # same as yours
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function that does that for a single row, and then `apply` it to each row. You can actually use the same function for both questions.

```
top_and_bottom <- function(x, k=3, ...) {
  o <- rank(x, ...)
  n <- length(x)
  ifelse( o <= k, -1, ifelse( o >= n-k+1, 1, 0 ) )
}   
n <- 10
k <- 7
Ret <- array(rnorm(k*n),dim=c(n,k))
select <- t(apply( Ret, 1, top_and_bottom, 3 ))
select <- abs(select)
signal <- array(rnorm(k*n),dim=c(n,k))
longshort <- t(apply(signal, 1, top_and_bottom, 2))
```

Edit: I had misunderstood the second part of the question.
The following should be closer to what you want.

```
longshort <- t(apply(
  # Replace the non-selected values by the median, 
  # to ensure they are not in the top or bottom.
  ifelse( select==1, t(signal), apply(t(signal), 1, median) ),
  1,
  top_and_bottom, 2
))
```

Comment: Still don't get same answer as the OP. Try `set.seed(1)` before generating the data and then compare...